# CentOS 6.2 - I can't access console using Alt+Ctrl+F2 (F1 to F6)

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rhel6, centos6.2

I can't switch to tty console (text mode) using Alt+Ctrl + F1 to F6

What I found on the net is that Alt+Ctrl+F1 is now the X server (which was on F7 before). However Alt+Ctrl+F2 to F6 also doesn't work.

edit: 
Some googling led to this: How to disable Alt-Ctrl-Fx switching to a console - put this in xorg.conf:

```
Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
```

How to do that when there is NO xorg.conf. How can I set these X options .. can it be done using xrandr (console app used to configure X in RHEL6, also found by googling)?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant files appear to be

```
   /etc/init/start-ttys.conf
   /etc/init/tty.conf
```

It used to be handled in /etc/inittab, but the new init machinery changed that.

Comment: I also found that these files are relevant. tried to "guess" how exactly, but it didn't work - it's not made for guessing. Couldn't find where it's documented too. All they say is "this is removed, that's removed", but they don't say how to do the old stuff with the new tools

Comment: Unfortunately, all my centos6 machines are virtualized, have no standard console, so I cannot do "consoel tests".

Comment: I'm trying centos 6 on a vmware virtual machine ... with a console